# border overflow 100% height width body mobile browser?

Tags: html, css, mobile

### I have the following DIV structure:

```
<style>
#header{border-bottom:1px solid blue;}
#footer{botter-top:1px solid blue;}
#header,#footer{height:15%;}
#content{height:70%;}
#header,#footer,#content{width:100%;}
</style>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

*What I'm noticing is that in desktop browsers, there is an expected overflow with a 2px+ offset from 100%*
**However, in mobile browsers, there does not seem to be any overflow / scrolling.**

- Do mobile devices count borders as part of the 100% height/width calculations?

### If so:

- Is there a way to invoke this behavoir through CSS for desktop browsers?
- Is there a way to reverse this behavoir through CSS for mobile browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes, desktop browsers will see a 2px offset, because the spec says take 100% of the parent + border + margin.  The mobile browsers don't seem to be affected, but mostly because they are trying to autofit content to the window to eliminate scrolling.

There are 2 css3 fixes, the first being to use the new box-sizing property, and setting it to border-box.  The second is to use the flexbox model.  But unfortunately older browsers may not support either of these solutions.

So I would use box-sizing, but put an IE conditional statement in to account for IE7 and back,  and just use javascript or a css hack to fix it.

**edit**

here is the solution using box-sizing http://jsfiddle.net/aaFHZ/

```
body, html {height:100%; width: 100%;}
#header{border-bottom:1px solid blue;}
#footer{border-top:1px solid blue;}
#header,#footer{height:15%;}
#content{height:70%;}
#header,#footer,#content{width:100%; box-sizing:border-box;}
```

and here is the solution with flexbox (note: this will only work on the most current browsers) http://jsfiddle.net/YkSYN/1/

```
<style>
body, html {height:100%; width: 100%;}
#header{border-bottom:1px solid blue;}
#footer{border-top:1px solid blue;}
#header,#footer {
    -webkit-box-flex: 15;
    -moz-box-flex: 15;
    box-flex: 15;}
#content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 70;
    -moz-box-flex: 70;
    box-flex: 70;}
#header,#footer,#content{width:100%;}
#wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    display: box;
    box-orient: vertical;
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: be so kind to supply both case senarios ive requested above? =)

Answer (score 1):

Every browser (mobile and desktop) with default `box-sizing` should add the 2px.

Try to add this rule:

`#header,#footer,#content { box-sizing:border-box; }`

To your CSS.

---

- Is there a way to invoke this behavoir through CSS for desktop browsers?

No need for it. It's already the default behavior.

- Is there a way to reverse this behavoir through CSS for mobile browsers?

Yes, by adding the rule above :-) or the workaround at the bottom of this answer.

---

If you want to target mobile devices only, nest the rule in a media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
    #header,#footer,#content { box-sizing:border-box; }
}
```

To make it work on IE8, use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). But if you only have this media query, probably you actually don't need it (it will be simply ignored).

The `box-sizing` property [is very well supported by browsers](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) (IE8+, all the rest), i don't think you need a fallback for IE7 (less then 2% users worldwide).

---

Another really simple workaround for your problem is to add negative margin of 1px:

```
#footer,#content { margin-top:-1px; }
```

This will solve the issues in mobile devices and any known browser.

Comment: be so kind to supply both case senarios ive requested above? =)